# Insert rows as soon as the table is created - Oracle

Tags: java, oracle

I tried to insert a set of rows as soon as a table is created using the following query in Java as followed:

```
DECLARE tbl_exist  PLS_INTEGER; 
BEGIN 
select count(*) into tbl_exist  from user_tables where table_name = 'REPRO_PRINTING_JOB_STATE'; 
if tbl_exist = 0 then 
    execute immediate 'create table REPRO_PRINTING_JOB_STATE ( 
    ID varchar2(2) not null primary key, 
    NAME varchar(255) not null )'; 
    execute immediate 'insert into REPRO_PRINTING_JOB_STATE (ID, NAME) values ('QU','IN THE QUEUE')'; 
    execute immediate 'insert into REPRO_PRINTING_JOB_STATE (ID, NAME) values ('IN','INCIDENT')'; 
    execute immediate 'insert into REPRO_PRINTING_JOB_STATE (ID, NAME) values ('CM','COMPLETED')'; 
    execute immediate 'insert into REPRO_PRINTING_JOB_STATE (ID, NAME) values ('PR','PROCESSING')'; 
    execute immediate 'insert into REPRO_PRINTING_JOB_STATE (ID, NAME) values ('CN','CANCELLED')'; 
end if; 
END;
```

It failed. Was this because the use of "execute immediate" statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your first iteration of the question, it probably fails because your first insert is into a totally *different* table:

```
execute immediate 'insert into PRINTING_JOB_STATE (ID, NAME) values ... '
execute immediate 'insert into REPRO_PRINTING_JOB_STATE (ID, NAME) values .... '
```

In other words, you're using `PRINTING_JOB_STATE` instead of `REPRO_PRINTING_JOB_STATE`.

---

However, now that you've confirmed that was just a simple typo on your part, you need to check your use of the single quotes in the insert statements. The fact that your dynamic string is surrounded by `'` characters means that *using* `'` inside the string (around things like `QU`) will be problematic.

You'll probably need to escape the quotes by using duplicated quotes, such as with:

```
execute immediate 'insert into XYZZY (ID, NAME) values (''QU'', ''QUEUED'')';
```

That's two *single* quotes on either side of the `QU` and `QUEUED`, not a double quote.

Comment: Apologies about that mistake. The real query is actually correct.

Comment: thank you for your respond so are you suggesting that I should use " over strings instead?

Comment: No, that appears to be a _single_ character, the double quote. I'm suggesting you use _two_ characters, both single quotes. In other words a double single quote rather than a single double quote. Hope that clears it up :-)